# Typescript não está checando tipos em map com operador spread

Tags: array, typescript, map

O seguinte código compila sem nenhum tipo de warning. É alguma configuração que está errada/faltando?

```js
interface CategoryInfo {
  name: {
    portuguese: string
    english: string
    spanish: string
  }
  icon: string
  categoryId: number
  active: boolean
  benefits: number
  subscribers: number
  createdAt: string
  updatedAt: string
  deletedAt?: string
}

export function formatFetchCategoriesResponse(
  response: CategoryInfo[]
): CategoryInfo[] {
  return response.map((category) => ({
    ...category,
    aPropertyThatDoesntExists: 'Anything',
  }))
}
```

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "ESNext.AsyncIterable", "DOM"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "types": [
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/types",
      "ant-design-vue/types",
      "@nuxtjs/axios",
      "@nuxtjs/auth-next"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para quem está na duvida do porque o código acima compila sem erros, o problema está na tipagem do retorno da função de *callback* passada para o método `.map`:

```
return response.map((category) => ({ // <= neste ponto
    ...category,
    aPropertyThatDoesntExists: 'Anything',
  }))
```

Isso tem sido reportado como um bug (ou não) [aqui](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31425) e [aqui](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241) do TypeScript, onde o mesmo adiciona o campo extra na tipagem de retorno. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
type User = { name:string }
const users: Array<User> = [1,2,3].map((age) => ({ name:'Georges', age: age }))
```

Se você rodá-lo no [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3lAdgQwLYQBccwiAllgOZQC%20AUAMYD2WJUArgonIVAIKJEOEAB54SAHyooAbQCMAGgBMCgMwBdAHR4cYABR6clCAEpUUvZlwFCAcgDiEJomNxbCqEaKfjtEyaA), não irá retornar erro algum:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A propriedade `age` foi adicionada ao tipo de retorno desse *callback* do `map`, como se fosse uma extensão do `type User`, logo o retorno passou a ser um array de:

```
map<{
    name: string;
    age: number;
}>
```

Repare que este comportamento não está restritamente relacionado com o operador *spread*, mas sim com o método de array `map`.

Alguns dizem que isto é bug... outros dizem que não há problema... outros dizem para simplesmente ignorar.

O que é? *Bug* ou *Feature inesperada*?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mesmo comportamento inesperado está acontecendo no código do autor da pergunta. Se olharmos o retorno da função de *callback* do método `map`, estará como:

```
(method) Array<CategoryInfo>.map<{
    aPropertyThatDoesntExists: string; // olha a surpresa aqui
    name: {
        portuguese: string;
        english: string;
        spanish: string;
    };
    icon: string;
    categoryId: number;
    active: boolean;
    benefits: number;
    subscribers: number;
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
    deletedAt?: string | undefined;
}>(callbackfn: (value: CategoryInfo, index: number, array: CategoryInfo[]) => {
    ...;
}, thisArg?: any): {
    ...;
}[]
```

Observe que foi adicionada a tipagem `aPropertyThatDoesntExists: string;`, por isso o retorno abaixo foi considerado válido e não gerou erro algum:

```
return response.map((category) => ({
    ...category,
    aPropertyThatDoesntExists: 'Anything',
  }))
```

O que pode ser feito é **explicitamente indicar** o tipo de retorno deste *callback*. No exemplo acima, devemos explicitamente indicar o tipo **`CategoryInfo`** como retorno:

```
return response.map((category): CategoryInfo => ({ ...
```

Veja no [Playground TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJ0gcwPZQJ4CSIM2yA3gFDLIhwC2EAXOVdcgA65gCum3EAZybIBYKKEytqEEJgA2wAQAtmo8bKkj2cEIpUixE1gF9WwBNhCrDG6ggwQc+AgBNmIbnQBG0VojDAAG7CXtjYchA6rD4gEDDAYALunj5QrALcXgII4qlJNCm+dlCRkC4AgmDW6pLU3OwuDhVVBjWsLhARZZUA-NVGphQw3CAIAZbIJFB0GABiEGAISuhYuMCCAEqCnCBCABSsJQI7QswrjriExNgA2gC6FACUZw5OVyT3LNQlPFAgyEcThAAHQzdh7Pb2Vb4Z5oV6XIgkZAAXgAfMg9pQ2MhgbioRd8AAaTRwAAKUGw7GgYDwABUlBgACLYQTgACiAA9FIlmABycogPBgJQSXnE6jGR6PCjGIA) que o código ira apresentar um erro quando adicionado `aPropertyThatDoesntExists`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que é o comportamento esperado pelo autor da pergunta.

Para resolver o erro, agora devemos remover a propriedade `aPropertyThatDoesntExists` do objeto de retorno para respeitar a interface `CategoryInfo`:

```
function formatFetchCategoriesResponse(
  response: CategoryInfo[]
): CategoryInfo[] {
  return response.map((category): CategoryInfo => ({
    ...category
  }))
}
```